# Strokewidth is inconsistent for outliers in react-boxplot module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, graph, boxplot

I'm using [react-boxplot](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-boxplot/v/3.1.0) module

I want to make my outlier look like a ring highlighted in the Image shared
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLBkD.png)

Here's my code

```
<Boxplot
            width={boxplotWidth}
            height={20}
            min={1}
            max={6}
            stats={{
              whiskerLow: 2,
              quartile1: 2.5,
              quartile2: 3.5,
              quartile3: 4.5,
              whiskerHigh: 6,
              outliers: [4],
            }}
            outlierRadius={6}
            outlierStyle={{
              fill: 'transparent',
              fillOpacity: '0',
              stroke-width: '1',
              stroke: 'orange',
            }}
            boxStyle={{ fill: '#A3D7CA' }}
            medianStyle={{ stroke: '#3D4E59' }}
          />
```

But when I give stroke-width and stroke then click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvKbw.png) to see what happens.

I know this is something to do with transform property on the g tag but I'm not understanding.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not very sure this is what you are asking. You must know that when using `stroke-linecap: round` the roundness of the line adds to the length and in very thick lines this will be very obvious

Answer (score 0):

I took a quick read of the library - I'm not quite sure I follow it, but try:

```
    outlierRadius={1}
    outlierStyle={{
      fill: 'transparent',
      fill-opacity: '0',
      stroke-width: '0.03',
      stroke: 'orange',
    }}
```